# Rapid Authentication and Configuration in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I'm trying to add authentication to my Laravel project. My database configuration is:

```
'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'strict' => true,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

And the *.env* file contains:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=example
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

When I try to register, this error happens:

[image: Image of the error message]

I'm using XAMPP and my phpMyAdmin table structure is shown in this picture:

[image: Image of the users table structure]

Comment: remember_token is set to `NOT NULL` but you're not providing a value for it. You need to either provide a value for it or change the schema to allow NULL.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Its because remember_token field is not allowing to store null.

so either you need to provide value for remember_token or allow remember_token to have null values.

Comment: Can you please tell me how do I set up in the migrations file? I know in the database how to do null remember_token allow